# I want to make these table columns stack when on mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have 5 columns, I have them as table as it was the easiest way for me to code it.

I want to make them stack on mobile view. How do I go about doing this?

The format I have is:

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-header-group;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried setting the content class to width of 100% using the media query. I want them to stack if that is possible. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

I tried using flexbox before the table method but ran into issues regarding the height when the screen size changed and this was easier for me to do, I just don't know how to make it mobile responsive. Because it is not an actual table I am getting a little confused.

Comment: Flexbox or Grid would be a better way to handle this layout, **unless** it's actual table data. What height issues were you having on mobile? It looks like there should be images here. Are the images all the same height?

Comment: You want 5 columns become 5 rows?

Comment: @disinfor the actual content is not table data. i will have another look at the flexbox layout instead, thank you.

Comment: @Katie I gave you a real simple answer, but can also provide a flexbox solution, but still would like to know the height issue you ran into.

Comment: @disinfor [link](https://gyazo.com/81e721e7c0b61cd983fce6de67d27f30) the columns were going like this when the screen size was smaller and i wanted them to stack on top. In regards to the flexbox height issue, the columns would all be different heights due to different amounts of content in them. I went back to the flexbox method and started from scratch and was able to resolve it but I am not entirely sure what I did different. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way to do this, if you like your setup for desktop currently, is to wrap all your CSS above in a `@media` query for larger screens. Like `@media (min-width: 768px) { ... all your CSS }` - this way, nothing on mobile will be affected by those styles. And by default, `div` are block-level elements and will be 100% and stack.

```css
/* COMMON STYLES THAT WILL AFFECT ALL SCREENS - just for presentation and can be removed */

.content {
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: blue;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* now this will only apply to larger screens */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .content {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* REMOVE THIS from your real code, just a reset from the global above */
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: transparent;
    height: auto;
  }
  .content img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-header-group;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made using grid, but I think it's possible to use flex too:

```
#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 10px;
    height: 50vh;
}

.content {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    } 
}
```